# Place three DIV boxes horizontally and centered

Tags: css, html, alignment

I'd like to place three DIV boxes horizontally and centered. If i resize (narrower) the browser boxes should take place vertically and centered.

----BrowserWide-----

__*_*___*X X X****_*__*_*__**

----BrowserWide-----

----BrowserNarrow-----

__*_*__*_*__*X****_*__*_*__*_*__**

__*_*__*_*__*X****_*__*_*__*_*__**

__*_*__*_*__*X****_*__*_*__*_*__**

----BrowserNarrow-----

This is my html:

```
 <div class="premium_features"> 
  <div class="premium1">
   <h2>Some Heading</h2>
   <p>Some paragraph, Some paragraph, Some paragraph, Some paragraph, Some paragraph, 
   </p>
  </div>    
  <div class="premium2">
   <h2>Some Heading</h2>
   <p>Some paragraph, Some paragraph, Some paragraph, Some paragraph, Some paragraph, 
   </p>
  </div>    
  <div class="premium3">
   <h2>Some Heading</h2>
   <p>Some paragraph, Some paragraph, Some paragraph, Some paragraph, Some paragraph, 
   </p>
  </div>    
 </div>
```

This is my css:

```
.premium1 {

    background: url("4.png") no-repeat top center;
    padding-top: 95px;
    float:left;
    width: 33%;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 320px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

}

.premium2 {

    background: url("5.png") no-repeat top center;
    padding-top: 95px;
    float:left;
    padding-top: 95px;
    float:left;
    width: 33%;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 320px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

}


.premium3 {

    background: url("6.png") no-repeat top center;
    padding-top: 95px;
    float:left;
    width: 33%;
    height: 100px;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 320px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

}

.premium_features {

    width: 75%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
```

With this code: It is OK when it is wide and when it is narrow. 
But during resize 2 of 3 boxes are staying at the same block for a while. I need to sort them vertically when resizig starts.

Thanks for help.

Comment: If you want help, you're going to have to show what you've tried.  SO isn't free work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please show us your current code?

Comment: @Daedalus I've shared my code. Maybe you want to help now.

Comment: @Benesh Thank you! I've just added my code. Sorry, I couldn't do it at first.  Maybe you can help now.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to centre elements:

Margin way:

With a set width or display: inline-block; you can use:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

text-align way:

With a set width or display: inline-block; you can add this to the parent:

```
text-align: center;
```

Absolute way:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: width/2;
```

or

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(0, -50%);
```

Also don't worry too much about ie7 and below as the the majority of people use higher versions of ie or a different browser though this should work up until ie6

Answer (score 0):

Place your three divs within one large div and style that div

```
#largeDiv{ margin : 0 auto 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is what you meant:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="longone">long one</div>
<center>
<div id="box"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
<div id="box"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
<div id="box"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
</center>
```

**CSS:**

```
#longone
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#box
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R9ENg/

Although, personally, I'd use `<ul>`s and `<li>`s.

Comment: Thank you but i've different content at each div like background image. So would you see my code above?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/a2cPu/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-wrapper">
    <div class="container-1"></div>
    <div class="container-2"></div>
    <div class="container-3"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container-wrapper {
    text-align:center;
}
.container-1, .container-2, .container-3 {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:-4px;
}
.container-1 {
    background:red;
    margin-left:0;
}
.container-2 {
    background:green;
}
.container-3 {
    background:blue;
}
@media all and (max-width: 650px) {
    .container-1, .container-2, .container-3 {
        width:100%;
        display:block;
        margin:0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but i've different content at each div like background image. I couldnt display the images at browser somehow. So would you see my code above?

Answer (score 0):

you can use mediaqueries and test screenwidth to apply different style :
example mediaquerie + `display:flex;`

demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmFlt/

```
    #container {
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:row;
      justify-content:center;
    }
    #container div {
      width:200px;
      height:100px;
      background:gray;
      margin:auto 1em;
    }
/* next block, @media, can be clone to set other media queries */
    @media only screen 
    and (max-width : 800px) {/* under 800px width , this CSS is overriding precedent rules */
      #container {
      flex-direction:column;
    }
      #container div {
        margin:1em auto;
    }
```

```
<div id = "container">
  <div>box
  </div>
  <div>box
  </div>
  <div>box
  </div>
</div>
```

You can do it setting `display:inline-block` / `block` the `#container div` and drop the `display flex` rules for `#container`, keep margins for the 3 div .

demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/utflx/

Comment: Thank you but i've different content at each div like background. So would you see my code above again?

Comment: there no problem giving backgrounds to div , you may resize their width too inside mediaquerie if 33% is then too little , you can set auto or 90% there. DEMOS are on line, try and master them to find out how it works, what mediaqueries does and is for :).